# My Bootstrap carousel are not giving the slides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I copied a Bootstrap carousel code to understand how it works but the code isn't giving me the desired result. The slides aren't moving.The first slide is just stagnant. Please what do you reccommend I do? Here are the html and css codes. I also included a screenshot of it for more clarification.

html

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: red;">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: yellow;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: purple;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 500px;   
}
```

[image: Snippet of my html and css codes]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Did you copy the Bootstrap JS as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the proper parent with the appropriate `id` and `data-ride` that correlates with Bootstrap. Then you need to add the relative JS and CSS for [Bootstrap 4.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/)

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: red;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: yellow;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: purple;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting dear. I applied it and it worked. I'm really grateful. I'll always use the  relative JS and CSS when I'm using a external library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside "head" tag of your .html file.

Why do you need to add this? The answer is whenever you are using a 3rd party library either you need to install it in your project or use its CDN to make it work.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, why should OP add this to the HTML file? Answers should explain **why** not just a short snippet of code.

Comment: Ok Waleed, doing that now. Thanks for your response

Comment: @disinfor Thank you for the suggestions. Kieni do let me know if you had any questions in mind.

Comment: I have added them inside the head tag of my .html file but it is still showing the same thing. Please what else do I do? Thank you. @WaleedRafi

Comment: from where did you copy this code? share website link

Comment: This is the website dear https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/